# Cannot hit ASP.NET Core API from remote computer on network

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I created the sample dotnet webapi project via `dotnet new webapi` (v3.1.101) and updated launchSettings.json's `applicationUrl` to first `http:*:5000` then to `http:0.0.0.0:5000`. When I try to go to `http://<MY_COMPUTER_NETWORK_NAME>:5000/WeatherForecast`, it times out, yet when I locally try `http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast`, it works.

I ran a React App on port 5000 and I could successfully connect to it remotely, so I don't think it is a firewall issue.

I am running on a Mac. I also tried adding `.UseUrls(...)` without success.

Why can't I connect remotely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a firewall?

Comment: I have one in place but I verified via the React App that port 5000 was open

Comment: Silly question: did you restarted your application after modifying launch settings, didn't you?

Comment: @Ian - what the heck? Running it in debug mode works! How do I get it to run correctly in terminal, I wonder?

Comment: @ClaudioValerio - a completely valid question. Yes, I did.

Comment: @CodeSlinger512 - Changed comment to answer, since it appears to be one. Also added link that describes how to use terminal (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using VSCode in Windows and I've noticed I cannot use the dotnet run command from the terminal, I have to hit play from the Debug sidebar window for it to work, and then I can connect from other computers on the same network.

If you would like to launch with the terminal, then I think you have to manually specify your launch.json file in the options. See the --launch-profile option here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

Answer (score 3):

`dotnet run` will try to automatically load `MyApplication\Properties\launchSettings.json`.
If file launchSettings.json exists and "all addresses" binding is set:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Uno": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then running the application should give this result:

```
> dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
    Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
    Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

and checking open ports:

```
> netstat -na | ? { $_ -match "5000|5001" }
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

If launchSettings.json does not exist or exist with different name, default binding will apply:

```
> mv .\Properties\launchSettings.json .\Properties\launch.json
> dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
```

unless you specify the urls using specific option:
server.urls="http://0.0.0.0:5000;https://0.0.0.0:5001"

Also note that the first time that any application tries to bind to 0.0.0.0:port, a window like this appears:
[image]
It is very easy to miss it if you are in multi monitor setup or if you immediately focus on other windows. Also, this dialog will set an application specific firewall rule, so maybe you created the rule for the React application and not the rule for the dotnet app.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had set those fields set in `launchSettings.json` to `0.0.0.0` and the output looked as you had shown. I'm also running on a Mac, not Windows.